# The module has not been Deployed [Glassfish 4.0]

Tags: java, web-applications, ejb, glassfish-4

I am new to EJB and trying to create a EJB Application..But when I deploy my project after creating entity class and session class, I am getting the following error...

```
Initial deploying contact to F:\JavaAptech\contact\dist\gfdeploy\contact
Completed initial distribution of contact
GlassFish Server 4, deploy, null, false
F:\JavaAptech\contact\nbproject\build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Can anyone help me ??

Comment: open build-impl.xml file from error window. and post your line no 307. Its impossible for us giving you any suggestion by your question.

Comment: @AdityaEkbote thnk you for your response..but I got the solution myself :)

Comment: Post your solution for future user.